Fantasy/Adventure movie from 2000s young guys being chased by a demon/summoned monster
I'm searching for a Fantasy/Adventure/Horror movie (or maybe a film of 2 parts) from the around 2000s (maybe a bit earlier).
I think it was an American movie (or at least it was in English).
The plot: As I said, it was a Fantasy movie, an adventure and and also had some frightening scenes. It was about two boys and one girl (or one boy and one girl) who went to something like a magic school (or some kind of university) and they were learning some things about magic/magic rituals.
During one night, they went to the forest and had some kind of competition with some other guys and the main character did something that was forbidden (like a forbidden ritual) and summoned a demon or something like that (they called it a Gebet or Gebeth, not sure ...). Then, the guy was expelled from the school, because this monster was going to chase him (I don't know why) and they could not protect him. That's basically what I remember ...
If anyone has any idea, I would be grateful!

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Sounds like Earthsea (or Legend of Earthsea ), which was indeed a 2-part miniseries, from 2004.

In the land of Earthsea, a young wizard named Ged has visions about a girl and doors opening. [...] A magus named Ogion arrives at Ged's village and revives Ged. He tells Ged his true name and takes him for training, but Ged is too impatient; he is sent to the magic school on Roke. There he meets the bully, Jasper, and befriends a student named Vetch. Ged shapeshifts into a hawk to show off. Jasper then challenges him to raise a spirit from the dead, leading him to accidentally release a Nameless One. The demon attacks Ged before being driven away by the Archmagus, who tells him that this Nameless One will hunt Ged down and try to possess him, using Ged's power for further destruction. Ged must go somewhere in hiding until he can find its true name and destroy it.

The 'nameless' demon is a Gebbeth. Based on the Earthsea books. Here's the trailer:




Exactly the one I was searching for ! Well, my description is far from being right, but you got it anyway ! Thanks a lot !!!
